# Template not loaded after dynamic bootstrap

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

In our application, we load and we destroy components every time we navigate through the website. The code for this is very simple :

```
loadComponent(): void {
        if (appCmp != undefined)
            appCmp.destroy();

        appCmp = this.appRef.bootstrap(Main);
}
```

We destroy the old component, and we bootstrap the new one.

This works and I can see my component is loaded, but it seems that it's not initialized : the template is not loaded. You can see that my buttons here are not shown correctly :

[image: You can see that my buttons here are not shown correctly]

The correct template is here :

[image: The correct template]

PS : I already tried `.detectChanges()` but it don't work.
The template is finally loaded when I move the mouse.
Any ideas ?

**EDIT1**: I saw that `ngAfterViewInit` is not called, can it be a bug ?

Comment: is there any reason for not using the in-built [Angular2 Component Router?](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Comment: Yes we make a server process before returning the view

Comment: Can you reproduce it on the plunker?

Comment: I will try if I found the time. I noticed that the change detector don't detect the changes anymore, even if I call `reattach`